# Generate Random Matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random

Is there any way in Matlab to generate a 5000 x 1000 matrix of random numbers in which:

```
MM = betarnd(A,B,1,1000);
```

but A and B are vectors (1 x 5000). I get the following error message:

```
??? Error using ==> betarnd at 29
Size information is inconsistent.
```

I want to avoid a loop like the following one:

```
for ii = 1 : 1000
  MM(:,ii) = betarnd(A,B); 
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific need to use A and B as 1x5000 arrays?

Comment: @madbitloman I assume because there are 5000 different values

Comment: From your code I think you want a 1000x5000 matrix, not 5000x1000. Right?

Comment: hi there, thanks for the answers. @madbitloman, yes, I need the 5000 values because I need to sample that much pdfs. Luis, yes you're right. As I wrote it, it should be 1000x5000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat `A` and `B` (vectors of size 1x5000) to obtain matrices of size 1000x5000 in which all rows are equal, and use those matrices as inputs to `betarnd`. That way you get a result of size 1000x5000 in which column `k` contains 1000 random values with parameters `A(k)` and `B(k)`.

The reason is that, according to the [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/betarnd.html) (emphasis mine):

> `R = betarnd(A,B)` returns an array of random numbers chosen from the
>       beta distribution with parameters `A` and `B`. **The size of `R` is the common size of `A` and `B` if both are arrays**.

So, use

```
MM = betarnd(repmat(A(:).',1000,1), repmat(B(:).',1000,1));
```

Comment: nice and clean. Thanks Luis!

Comment: @OliverAmundsen Great! I wasn't sure whether that was what you needed